# Confused how to type comparator in another class

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I am trying to sort the values of two LinkedHashMap.  I can compile it and run the code just fine, but it tells me to use -Xlint option during compiling because it is unsafe code.  It has something to do with type casting stuff, but I am royally confused on how to do it.  I got this class which I put inbedded in my class:

```
static class MyComparator implements Comparator {

        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2){
            int result=0;
            Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry)obj1 ;
            Map.Entry e2 = (Map.Entry)obj2 ;//Sort based on values.

            Integer value1 = (Integer)e1.getValue();
            Integer value2 = (Integer)e2.getValue();

            if(value1.compareTo(value2)==0){

                String word1=(String)e1.getKey();
                String word2=(String)e2.getKey();

                //Sort String in an alphabetical order
                result=word1.compareToIgnoreCase(word2);

            } else {
                //Sort values in a descending order
                result=value2.compareTo( value1 );
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
```

I tried to call it in one of my functions with:

```
ArrayList myArrayList=new ArrayList(this.map_freq_by_date.entrySet());
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new MyComparator());
Iterator itr=myArrayList.iterator();
```

Note: this.map_freq_by_date is defined as follows:

```
Map<String,Integer> map_freq_by_date = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

The error I get with -Xlint option:

```
unchecked call to ArrayList(java.util.Collection<? extends E>) as a member of the raw type java.util.ArrayList
ArrayList myArrayList=new ArrayList(this.map_freq_by_date.entrySet());


unchecked conversion
found LogGrep.MyComparator
required: java.util.Comparator(? super T>
    Collections.sort(myArrayList, new MyComparator());

unchecked method invocation: <T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<? super T> in java.util.Collections is applied to (java.util.ArrayList,LogGrep.MyComparator)
    Collections.sort(myArrayList, new MyComparator());
```

Help with how to fix these would be appreciated.  I looked online and tried all kinds of things shown, but I can't seem to get it right.

Note: if I put `ArrayList<Object> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Object>`... the error changes to:

```
unchecked method invocation <T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<> super T?) in java.util.Collections is applied ot (java.util.ArraList<java.lang.Object>,LogGrep.MyComparator)
        Collections.sort(myArrayList, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: It did not list my definition of map_freq_by_date as I intended in the question above.  It is defined as a LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>.

Answer (score 4):

Comparator is a Generic Interface. Do it like this:

```
static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> obj1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> obj2){
        ...
    }
}
```

and define your list as

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
```

And the compiler will be happy again.

Read [the Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for more info. Or [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Btw, unless your Comparator needs runtime parameters or has mutable state, you should define it as a Constant instead of creating a New instance for every call

Comment: I just realized that you want to compare map entries, not Integers. In that case, replace all occurrences of `Integer` with `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`

Comment: Thanks!  That got rid of the warnings.  Without -Xlint option there are no more warnings.  In case you know, what is the difference between using ArrayList<String,Integer> versus ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>?  Also, why was it necessary to change the ArrayList to List?

Comment: @user372429 ArrayList has only one type variable, so `ArrayList<String, Integer>` won't compile. It's not necessary to change the variable type to List, but it's considered good style to program against interfaces, not implementation types. Read [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 52: [Refer to objects by their interfaces](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/general-programming/ch08lev1sec8)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Comparator<T>` interface not a raw `Comparator`.

Read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a type safe way as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("four", 4);
map.put("one", 1);
map.put("five", 5);
map.put("three", 3);
map.put("two", 2);

System.out.println(map);

List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());        
Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
        return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
    }            
});        
map.clear();        
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : entryList) {
    map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{four=4, one=1, five=5, three=3, two=2}
{one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4, five=5}
```